# picking up rows with max values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, character, max

> a <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a")
>   b <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
>   c <- c("1","2","3","1","2","3")
>   df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
>   df1
>     a b c
>   1 a a 1
>   2 a a 2
>   3 a a 3
>   4 a b 1
>   5 a b 2
>   6 a b 3

just want show like this as result.(below)

a a 3
a b 3

Comment: Try with `aggregate(c~., df1, max)` after converting the 'c' column to `numeric`

Comment: thank you for quick answer. ^^